# 'self' is not defined error while using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Book')

class phonebook:
    def __init__(self,first_name, last_name, street, postcode, city, number):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.street = street
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.city = city
        self.number = number     

    def create(self):
        creation = tk.Tk()

        tk.Label(creation, text = 'First Name').grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Last Name').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Stadt').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Postleitzahl').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Straße').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
        tk.Label(creation, text = 'Telefonnummer').grid(row = 5, column = 0)

        self.first_name = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.last_name = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.street = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.postcode = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.city = tk.Entry(creation)
        self.number = tk.Entry(creation)   


menubar = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu = menubar)
menubar.add_command(label = 'Anlegen', command = self.create)
menubar.add_command(label = 'Bearbeiten')
menubar.add_command(label = 'Löschen')
menubar.add_command(label = 'Sortieren')
menubar.add_command(label = 'Suche')
menubar.add_command(label = 'Hilfe')

root.mainloop()
```

When I try the code above I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo M93p/Dropbox/Uni Dropbox/EPR/EPR_Blatt05_Jonas_Emrich_Karl_Wilhelm_Viebach/geathb.py", line 45, in <module>
    menubar.add_command(label = 'Anlegen', command = self.create)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

When I change:

```
menubar.add_command(label = 'Anlegen', command = self.create)
```

to:

```
menubar.add_command(label = 'Anlegen', command = phonebook.create)
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo M93p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I was trying to change something in the `create` function, changing the command line, but I get an error every time.

Comment: Quickly: create a `phonebook` object and call the `create` method on it instead of `self.create`

Comment: @KuKeC Your edit messed up the indentation!

Answer (score 3):

Less quickly:

In your original code, you are calling the `create` method on `self`, which is not declared in the scope.

You want to call the `create` method of the `phonebook` class, so you must instantiate the latter first. Basically, something like this:

```
p = phonebook(John, Doe, Evergreen Terrace, 12, Washington, 000)
p.create()
```

will work as intended. In your situation, you are calling that method through another one, which becomes:

```
p = phonebook(...)
menubar.add_command(label = 'Anlegen', command = p.create)
```

---

**Side note**

In Python, always name your classes starting with a capital letter, like `Phonebook`. This will avoid you confusions between classes and instances.